# Implicits not working as expected

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

The following code fails due to "could not find implicit value for rs":

```
import scalikejdbc.WrappedResultSet

object DatabaseSupport {
  implicit class WrappedResultSetConverter(columnName: String)(implicit rs: WrappedResultSet) extends AnyRef {
    def stringCol: String = rs.string(columnName)
    def intCol: Int = rs.int(columnName)
  }

  def myTest(rsParam: WrappedResultSet) {
      val a: String = "name".stringCol
      val b: String = WrappedResultSetConverter("name").stringCol
  }
}
```

I had thought that the *rsParam* parameter to *myTest* would be visible to the implicits?

Comment: You don't need to extend AnyRef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not visible because it is explicit, it should be made implicit via the implicit keyword.

On the other hand, implicit parameters can be passed as explicit ones to methods.